# How to iterate through pixels in a more efficient way?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an Image and convert it into a Bitmap. To check if the color of a pixel is between two values, I iterate through every single pixel of the given Bitmap. I create a new Bitmap, change the pixel if it is between these values and set.Pixel() on the new Bitmap, or leave the Pixel as it is and set it also on the new Bitmap. I reduced the Bitmap.Config from ARGB-8888 to RGB_565 but it is still unbeleavable slow and shows in debug "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Is there a better way to do that and make the app faster?

```java
 width = bitmap.getWidth();
        heigth = bitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, heigth, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < heigth; y++){
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
                float[] pixelHue = getHsv(pixel);
                if(pixelHue[0] > 170 && pixelHue[0] < 250 ){
                 //Change the Pixel
                    pixelHue[0] = pixelHue[0] - 17;
                    int newColor = setRgb(pixelHue);
                    newBitmap.setPixel(x, y, newColor);
                }
                else{
                      //leave the Pixel as it is
                    newBitmap.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
                }

            }
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }



private float[] getHsv (int pixel){
         int a = Color.alpha(pixel);
         int r = Color.red(pixel);
         int g = Color.green(pixel);
         int b = Color.blue(pixel);
         float[] hsv = new float[3];
         Color.RGBToHSV(r, g, b, hsv);
        return hsv;
    }


private int setRgb (float[] hsv){
        int rgb;
        rgb = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
        return rgb;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing it on the main thread?

Comment: Idk, I'm not a pro in programming and didn't work with threads so far. What should I do?

Comment: Use an [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: What is `getHsv`? Memory allocations in a tight loop like this can be a problem

Comment: @Joni its a method where I convert the rgb to hsv and give the hue, saturation , value  back. To check if the hue value is in between the two values

Comment: @DavidConrad I did it now with an AsyncTask, but its still very slow.

Comment: Can you share the code for getHsv and setRgb? Those it sounds like those are the only methods that do any actual work.

Comment: *I convert the rgb to hsv* - that is probably the expensive operation, so you want to minimize the number of times you do that. So create a HashMap of the Integer and Boolean value to indicate if the color falls in your range. So before doing the conversion you see if the pixel is in the HashMap. If you is you just return the Boolean value. If not, then do the conversion and add the Integer/Boolean to the HashMap.

Comment: @camickr but I need to check the hue value of a pixels color to indicate, if the color is in my range. So I need to convert the pixels color befor I can check this. Idk how to do that in another way. I don't know how to build the range in rgb for example.

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to check the hue value of a pixels color to indicate, if the color is in my range

Correct, but you don't need to convert the pixel to an HSV value every time. You can do the conversion once and then store the result.

So the basic structure of your code might be something like:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> pixels = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); // instance variable of your class

for(…)
{
    for (…)
    {
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y)
        int pixelHue = getPixelHue( pixel );
        newBitmap.setPixel(x, y, pixelHue);
    }
}

…

private int getPixelHue(int pixel)
{
    Integer pixelHue = pixels.get(pixel);

    if (pixelHue == null) // you haven't attempted to convert this pixel yet
    {
        float[] hsv = getHsv(pixel);

        if(hsv[0] > 170 && hsv[0] < 250 )
        {
            // Change the hue value of the hsv color
            hsv[0] = hsv[0] - 17;
            pixelHue = setRgb(hsv); // conversion done
        }
        else
        {
            pixelHue = pixel; // no conversion needed
        }

        pixels.put(pixel, pixelHue); // store result so we don't need to reconvert
    }

    return pixelHue;
}
```

So the HashMap will originally be empty. As you process a pixel of a unique color you will do the HSV conversion and hue conversion, if necessary, and store the result in the HashMap. The next time you process this pixel color you don't need to repeat the conversion process.